# What is it called when terms disappear when reducing fractions?

Tags: language-use

If $a = \frac{x}{b}$ and $a = \frac{c}{b}$, and I solve for $x$ I get $x = c$.

$b$ has been removed because it appeared in the numerator and the denominator.

What is it called in English what happened to $b$?

> $b$ ...

<sub>In German I would say "$b$ kürzt sich weg."</sub>

Comment: Simpler: $\color{#c00}{b^{-1}} x = \color{#c00}{b^{-1}} c\,\Rightarrow\, x=c\,$ by cancelling $\,\color{#c00}{b^{-1}},$ i.e. we can apply the **Cancellation Law** (rather than repeating its proof inline)

Comment: Note that your solution is incomplete. You are still left with the condition $ b \ne 0$ that must be tacked onto every conclusion that follows.

Comment: @jpmc26 Denominators of fractions are nonzero *by definition.*

Comment: @Number 1. Once you cancel it, it's not obvious there *is* a denominator. Stating the restriction explicitly makes it more clear that the condition applies to everything that follows. 2. $b$ may not have been defined as a denominator. The restriction still applies to conclusions that follow. 3. As this is an *educator* site, it's important to note that students can easily miss this important detail. 4. Depending on the starting equations, $b = 0$ may yield some other solution that needs to be found. Keeping in mind that this one doesn't work for that case helps you remember to look for it.

Comment: liguistically I understand cancel and eliminate as same thing.  Doesn't even give me pause.  http://ceemrr.com/Geometry2/Eliminating_Fractions/Eliminating_Fractions_print.html (many other examples available...GIYF)

Comment: @guest One can find all sorts of nonsense on random web pages. I was hoping for links to use by eminent authors, e.g. a professional algebraist.

Comment: @jpmc26 While I agree that such attention to detail is important in some contexts, it's not clear that is the case here. In some contexts there is no need to append the proviso $b\neq 0$ to the result, e.g. if our context is algebra (vs. analysis) where $f := f(x)$ denotes a polynomial then $ f = x^2/x\,\Rightarrow\, f = x$ is true even when $x=0$. In other contexts there may be ambient conventions in use that appropriately account for singularities.

Comment: @Number See point 3. We know for a fact that our audience does not consist of expert mathematicians that will instantly recognize the limitation.

Comment: @jpmc26 As I explained above it depends on the context (which is missing in the OP). The contexts I refer to do not require expert-level knowledge of mathematics.

Comment: A Google search comes up with plenty more examples.  And I am personally familiar with either term being used.  So...burden of proof on you, if you want to advocate the opposite.

Comment: @guest You have yet to provide even *one* link to a page that uses "eliminate" to mean "cancel", let alone one in a reputable publication (as I requested).

Comment: 1.  You only asked for one link to start.  2.  A Google search (it is your friend) shows several others.  3.  You continue to make a strong assertion of YOURS and then put burden of proof on others to disprove it.  Go make your own survey!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-ab&q=fraction+eliminate+algebra&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ_q2O_bvdAhUKTt8KHfc-AQQQvgUIKSgB&biw=1366&bih=654

Comment: @guest Please give a link to a *specific* (reputable) web page and *specific* location on that page showing use of "eliminate" to mean "cancel". You haven't given even one such example (none in your first link).. It is *your* claim that such usage exists so it is *your* burden of proof, not mine.

Comment: I was responding to you.  And you did in fact make a claim and then dump the burden of proof on the opposite.

Comment: And your initial comment did not ask for "eminent" and "respectable" web pages.  You are moving the goal posts.

Comment: All right.  I looked around and can't find any such use.  It seems like documents (going back to the 1880s) seem to be very doctrinaire about using certain terms for certain operations.  Cancel is used in context of fractions.  Elimination in context of simultaneous equations.  So I guess you are used to a certain term used for a certain operation.  See where you are coming from, now, number.  Just as a civilian, who uses words, it didn't seem strange to me since the words mean same thing, colloquially.  But it does seem that algebra texts reserve the words to distinct topics.

Comment: IOW, you seem to be right.

Comment: @guest Thanks for following up. I suspected based on my experience that such usage would be rare. But it appears it is even rarer than I surmised. I was hoping that someone would find a few interesting examples that might shed some light on the scope and origins of such usage.

Comment: @guest: In English "eliminate" and "cancel" are not exact synonyms, in either ordinary or mathematical use. In mathematics, eliminate is mostly used in the context of solving systems of equations by eliminating variables (as in Gaussian elimination, or other more sophisticated kinds of elimination); this use is classical (19th century), but persists in some limited contexts, e.g. linear algebra. Cancellation is used with a less precise meaning, and generally refers to reciprocal elimination - some quantity is eliminated from both sides of the equation via multiplication by its inverse.

Comment: @Dan The above discussion on "eliminate" vs. "cancel" is actually an offshoot of the discussion below Gerald's answer. I don't know why guest moved it here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you continue the operations until
$$\require{cancel}\frac{x}{b}=\frac{c}{b},\qquad\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)b=\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)b,\qquad x\left(\frac{b}{b}\right)=c\left(\frac{b}{b}\right),\qquad x\left(\frac{\cancel b}{\cancel b}\right)=c\left(\frac{\cancel b}{\cancel b}\right)$$
then $x=c$, I would say that you *cancelled the common factor $b$* in the fraction.

Comment: I would also say cancelled, but some folks prefer "reduced" as to distinguish from additive cancellation.

Answer (score 13):

So German "$b$ kürzt sich weg" becomes in English "$b$ cancels out".  We may also say "$b$ is eliminated".

Comment: I've never heard "eliminated" used as a synonym for "cancelled".  Do you have any links exhibiting such?

Comment: @Number I have heard it, but only from professors who are not native English speakers and are translating from their native languages. (That's not to say that it's incorrect, I just found it to be less common.)

Comment: I am used to either cancel or eliminate and it does not sound odd to my ear and I am a native English speaker.  http://ceemrr.com/Geometry2/Eliminating_Fractions/Eliminating_Fractions_print.html

Comment: See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Elimination_of_variables  It is true that "cancel" and "eliminate" sometimes have different meanings, but they both qualify as "variables disappear when solving".

Comment: @Gerald But your link refers to (Gaussian) elimination of variables in *systems* of (linear) equations, not to cancelling a factor in a *single* equation. I've never seen elimination used instead of cancellation in the single equation case as in the OP.

Comment: @Number Are you a native English speaker, and what country's dialect do you speak? I can assure you that I've never encountered an American in a STEM field who would bat an eye at using "cancelled" to describe eliminating multiplicative constants (even fractional ones) from equations. If anything, using "eliminate" is much less common.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, I'm American and I've been teaching algebra at all levels for almost 4 decades (e.g. I am one of the most active algebra and number theory teachers on Math.SE, and ditto for earlier sites like sci.math, Ask an Algebraist, etc). So I have broad exposure to English algebraic language.I don't recall ever seeing "eliminate" used instead of "cancel" in a reputable publication by an author whose first language is English.

Comment: Number:  It's good to have a good ear and to listen to your hunches but I would not be so quick to assume that your hunches are correct.  At this point, you are just saying "sounds strange to me" and putting burden of proof on others to disprove you.

Comment: @Number Classrooms and people standing at a black/whiteboard discussing math are not "reputable publications." Are you saying you've never heard anyone *say* "cancelled"? Or just that you've never seen it in peer reviewed work or something? And what about casual sources that are not "reputable"?

Comment: @guest Nothing I wrote here is based on "hunches". If anyone can supply  examples that contradict my claims about usage then  I would be most interested to see them.

Comment: @jpmc26 Please read more carefully.The discussion concerns whether  "eliminate $a$" is standard usage to describe the *cancellation* laws $\, ax = ac\,\Rightarrow\,x = c\ $ or $\ x = \dfrac{ac}a\,\Rightarrow\, x = c\quad$

Comment: @guest e.g. we can *cancel* $a$ from $\dfrac{ac+a^2}a$ to get $c+a$ but "eliminate $a$" is *not* what we did.

Comment: I would say “eliminate” when it’s deliberate (“To solve this, we need to eliminate one of the variables. Let’s start with $y$.”) and “cancel” without such emphasis (“Observe that the same expression appears both in the numerator and the denominator, so it cancels out.”)

Comment: @Roman But cancellation generally is *not* the same as variable elimination, e,g. see the counterexample I gave in the comment preceding yours.

Comment: @Number Makes sense. Then maybe a more accurate distinction would be that *cancellation* is removal of a factor together with its multiplicative inverse, which may or may not lead to *elimination* where one or more variables no longer participate in the expression.

Answer (score 8):

In general, as others have noted, if you have an equation such as
$$\frac{x}{b}=\frac{c}b$$
The step to get from there to
$$x=c$$
is typically referred to as **cancelling the denominator**. More generally, if you can just remove some piece of the equation, you can use the verb "cancel" both with that piece as the object and the subject. For instance:

- We cancel the denominators.
- The denominators cancel.

You can also use the phrasal verb "cancel out" as in "The denominators cancel out."

Comment: I've never heard that language used. Do you have links to its use in respectable texts? it is incorrect terminology because it is not the denominator $b$ that is being cancelled but instead its inverse $b^{-1} = 1/b$  Usually cancelling the denominator refers to $\,bc/b = c,$ i.e. cancelling $b$ from $bx = bc$ $\quad$

Comment: @Number Are you *sure* you've never heard this? It sounds like you're trying to be pedantically "correct" but not correct in terms of actual usage. "The b's cancel [out]" is surely a very common way that someone would describe this scenario. Certainly how I would say it. Usage is what matters, not technicality. And I'm unsure why "respectable texts" matter. Most people don't speak like how a textbook reads...

Comment: @only_pro I refer specifically to "cancelling the denominator(s)". For example, precisely what does the mean when applied to $\dfrac{bx}b = \dfrac{bc}b$?  Does it yield  $bx = bc$ (as in this answer) or $x = c$?

Answer (score 3):

Coming at this from a slightly more abstract point of view than the other answers, this is an application of the [multiplicative cancellation law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property) (over the rationals if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all integers; or over the reals if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers; or over the complex numbers; or whatever...).  Specifically, in this context, the cancellation law says:

> Let $q$, $r$, and $s$ be rational numbers (or real numbers, or complex numbers) with $q\ne 0$.  Then $q\cdot r = q\cdot s$ if and only if $r=s$.

Note that it is quite important here that $q \ne 0$.  If $q = 0$, then both $r$ and $s$ may be chosen freely, and no cancellation is possible. 
 Taking $q = \frac{1}{b}$ (assuming that $b\ne 0$, $q$ is well-defined and we automatically have $q\ne 0$), $r = x$, and $s = c$, the multiplicative cancellation law gives us
$$
\frac{x}{b} = \frac{c}{b}
\iff \frac{1}{b} \cdot x = \frac{1}{b} \cdot c
\iff x = c. $$
Because we are using the multiplicative cancellation law, the process is called *cancelling* or *cancelling out* the common factor (in this case, we are cancelling a factor of $\frac{1}{b}$).  Indeed, I think that a properly rigorous reading of this step would be "We cancel out a common factor of $\frac{1}{b}$."

It might also be reasonable to say that "We cancel the common factors from the denominators," or more simply "We cancel the denominators."  That said, because I am kind of pedantic, I would be a little hesitant to say that anything is being done to $b$.  We aren't really cancelling a factor of $b$, but rather a factor of $\frac{1}{b}$.

Comment: +1 Thanks for elaborating on the point I emphasized in comments